# How to curl git commit?

Tags: git, github, curl

I am trying to download to my laptop(credentials-netrc)

```
curl -o ~/.local/bin/git-credential-netrc https://github.com/git/git/commit/017b7c52fc00897c72f6c4808ded43c4c5f9c5b8
```

I got unexpected HTML file

```
            <div class="text-right">
              <div class="BtnGroup mt-1 mt-md-0 ml-2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline BtnGroup-item js-accept-analytics-cookies" type="button">Accept</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline BtnGroup-item js-reject-analytics-cookies" type="button">Reject</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="text-right py-3 border-top">
            <button class="btn btn-primary js-save-cookie-preferences" type="button" disabled>Save preferences</button>
          </div>
        </div>
</div></div>  </div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to checkout a specific commit without creating a local repository?

Comment: @RenéLink I think that I need whole repo.

Comment: Sadly the question has been closed. I think what you want is this: `curl -sL -o tmp.zip https://github.com/git/git/archive/017b7c52fc00897c72f6c4808ded43c4c5f9c5b8.zip && unzip tmp.zip`